# Splitting Logic, Data, Layout and "Hacks"

Tags: design-patterns, refactoring

Sure, we all heard of programming patterns such as MVVM, MVC and such.

But that isn't really what I'm looking into as Layout, Data and Logic is already pretty much split up (XML-Layout markup, Database, *insert your language of choice here*).

The platform I am developing for is hard to maintain over the updated versions and older OSes. The project significantly grew up over the last few months and dealing with different platform versions really is a pain.

For example simply disabling an user interface control for all existing versions took me around 40 lines of code in the logic layer, wrangling around with invocation, delegation, singletons that provide UI handling and so on.

Is there a clean way to keep track of those "hacks" by maybe excluding it into separate classes or even packages? Should I overwrite existing framework code in order to handle *my* requirements correctly? If so, does that concept have a name?

Comment: are your different versions point releases? e.g v1.0 v1.2 v2.0 etc.

Comment: Charles Lambert: How does that matter?

Comment: versions could also mean web version, desktop version, mobile version, etc.

Comment: I see your point. Yes, it's different "point releases". Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: Are you asking about **Factory** design patterns which provide appropriate objects based on run-time configuration (like OS version)?

Comment: S.Lott: Somehow, yes. Except it doesnt create/instanciate objects but provides methods/functions that do stuff depending on run-time configuration.

Comment: @fjdumont I think a **Factory** pattern is what you want... the runtime configuration would determine the class of object provided by the Factory, so you could get a subclass that overrides methods appropriately for the platform/environment.

Comment: I will have a deeper look into these. Feel free to post your explanations as an answer, I'll gladly mark them as such.

Answer (score 2):

Inversion of control could help combined with [feature toggles](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html). Try to put your hacks into derived classes that override certain bits. Alternatively you can sometimes do with an interface you could implement in an alternative way. Through dependency injection you can 'configure' any client code to unknowingly use your (temporary) hack.

For instance when using a MVC pattern you could derive from a certain controller. Override a method and make it return a different view then it would normally do.